# how to draw shapes in a PDF using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, draw

I have some existing PDF files and what I want is to highlight some content by overlaying circles or straight lines. I've looked at some NodeJS PDF libraries but couldn't find a solution (some libraries allow creating a PDF from scratch and draw into it; other libraries can modify existing PDFs, but do not support drawing).

A (Linux / OSX) command line solution (e.g. using ImageMagick or some other library) would be perfectly fine, too.

**Edit** I've since found out that with Image/GraphicsMagick I can in fact do sth. like `gm convert -draw "rectangle 20,20 150,100" xxx.pdf[7] xxx2.pdf`, but this (1) either draws on *all* pages or else only on a single one, but then the resulting PDF will only contain *that* page; (2) the output PDF will contain a bitmap image where I would prefer a PDF with text content.

**Edit** I've just found [HummusJS](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS) which is a NodeJS library to manipulate PDF files via declarative JSON objects. Unfortunately, apart from the scrace documentation, the unwieldy API (see below), the tests fail consistently and across the board with `Unable to create PDF file, make sure that output file target is available`.

**completely OT** not sure what it is that makes people think such utterly obfuscated APIs are better than simple ones:

```
var settings = {modifiedFilePath:'./output/BasicJPGImagesTestPageModified.pdf'}
var pdfWriter = hummus.createWriterToModify('./TestMaterials/BasicJPGImagesTest.PDF',settings);
var pageModifier = new hummus.PDFPageModifier(pdfWriter,0);
pageModifier.startContext().getContext().writeText('Test Text', ...
...
var copyingContext = inPDFWriter.createPDFCopyingContextForModifiedFile();

var thirdPageID = copyingContext.getSourceDocumentParser().getPageObjectID(2);
var thirdPageObject = copyingContext.getSourceDocumentParser().parsePage(2).getDictionary().toJSObject();
var objectsContext = inPDFWriter.getObjectsContext();

objectsContext.startModifiedIndirectObject(thirdPageID);
var modifiedPageObject = inPDFWriter.getObjectsContext().startDictionary();
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of helpers with HummusJS, to assist with what you are trying to do:

1. Adding content to existing pages - https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki/Modification#adding-content-to-existing-pages
2. Draw shapes - https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki/Show-primitives

using both, this is how to add a circle at 'centerx,centery' with 'radius' and border width of 1, to the first page of 'myFile.pdf'. The end result, in this case will be placed in 'modifiedCopy.pdf':

```js
var pdfWriter = hummus.createWriterToModify(
                                     'myfile.pdf',
                                     {modifiedFilePath:'modifiedCopy.pdf'});
var pageModifier = new hummus.PDFPageModifier(pdfWriter,0);
var cxt = pageModifier.startContext().getContext();
cxt.drawCircle(
              centerX,
              centerY,
              radius,
              {
                  type:stroke,
                  width:1,
                  color:'black'
              });
pageModifier.endContext().writePage();
pdfWriter.end();
```

3. General documentation - https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki

If the tests fail, check that an "output" folder exists next to the script being executed, and that there are permissions to write there.

Comment: after some trials that led to silent failures and segmentation faults, i managed to get your code working. In order to use your code, `stroke` should be changed to `'stroke'`, `centerX`, `centerY` and `radius` should be set to numerical values (what unit are they then in?), and `hummus` has to be `require`d. Just saying because with such a difficult API you can't expect readers to 'just know' how to do things. Also, `cd node_modules/hummus && node runTests.js` will produce dozens of error messages `TypeError: Unable to create PDF file, make sure that output file target is available`.

Comment: ah yes, and I want the markers to be *below* the text in the background of the page so they don't cover anything; using your method gives me drawings on the top layer. Is there any way to control the z-placement?

Comment: glad you could run the script.

Comment: I'm afraid that PDFPageModifer is built only to add things on top of the existing page at this point. 

To do what you are looking for you will can start a fresh PDF and either append pages from the source pdf, or create pages, and merge the source pdf pages to them - this way overlaying the source pdf page on top of what drawings you wish to make in the page. Using this method you can also add drawings on top of the imported page, if you wish to.

To read about importing PDFs use this link - https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki/Embedding-pdf.

Good luck.